# php abstract class property from another abstract class

Tags: php, oop, abstract

I'm learning oriented object PHP and I think that I'm doing something stupid.

I have an abstract userManager class, and I want to assign it a $db property that will be the instance of my abstract database class.

The database class is :

```
abstract class Bdd{         
        private static $instance = null;

        public static function getInstance() {
            return self::$instance;
        }
```

And the userManager class is :

```
abstract class usersManager{
        public $db = Bdd::getInstance();
```

I have an error on this line : `public $db = Bdd::getInstance();`

(Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';')

Is this wrong ?

I think that I misunderstood the abstract classes, is a singleton better in my case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant call a method when you are declaring a class variable, you will need to do

```
public $db = null
public function __construct() {
  $this->db = Bdd::getInstance();
}
```

The only gotcha with this is when you extend this class and you need to create a constructor you will need to call this constructor as well by doing `parent::__construct();`

Comment: It seems legit but my class is abstract and the __construct method isn't called...

Comment: Doesnt matter that it is abstract, the __construct function will be called, unless like my answer states that in your child class you are already declaring the __construct method, in which case you will need to call parent::___construct()

Comment: I checked the doc and your right, but even if i do public function __construct() {
   echo 'CONSTRUCT';
  } The construct function is not called and I don't understand why. Another method of this class is called.

Comment: can you post some of the code from your child class. Are you sure it extends the parent class?

Comment: I don't have child class, just 2 abstract classes, and one must get the database instance from another.

Comment: I think i misunderstood abstract classes. I will try to replace it by a normal class with a singleton pattern. It should be (i hope) more suitable. Thanks for help

Comment: Ok I accept, this works very well ! And everything seems easier to me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public $db = Bdd::getInstance();
```

Error occurs due to above line. You can't call a method when declaring variable.

Answer (score 0):

Class parameters must be able to be evaluated at compile-time, NOT run-time. Basically you can only predefine simple values such as strings, null, int's e.c.t.

Because the result of `Bdd:getInstance()` cannot be known until it is run (i.e. run time), it cannot be used as a predefined value.

You should instead set the parameter to null, then set up the DB instance in your classes constructor method.